# Bluetooth characteristics scan

Tags: bluetooth, qt, embedded-linux

I am developing a bluetooth application for an embedded linux device. On the hardware I have an `IMX 6 MCU` and `EMMY W161` communication module. The operating system is a Yocto Project distribution (`Poky`). My main purpose is send and receive data from a smartwatch like industrial device. A bare metal embedded C firmware runs on this device and I don't have the source code. To test my code I downloaded an application on my cell phone and used it as a server. With my cell phone everything works perfectly. However, when I try to use the original device as the server, the client doesn't discover the server characteristics and after a certain time I see connection timeout error. I see the characteristics when I set my cell phone as a client. I have already set supervision time out and latency to the maximum values. I use QT libraries and bluez stack.

In a brief explanation the embedded linux device is able to send data to the cell phone. The cell phone is able to discover the characteristics of the target server device. Embedded linux device connects to the target server device and discovers the services but doesn't discover the characteristics. I don't understand why the embedded linux client doesn't discover the characteristics of the target server.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example in the QT, it is called Bluetooth low energy scanner.
Please post some code, to be able to follow your problem. Put this line as the first line in the main, it will show you some debuging logs.

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(QStringLiteral("qt.bluetooth* = true"));
```